# Best way to store comments and replies and querying in hierarchical manner in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to store comments and its replies and want to query such that each comment has its own replies inside an array in a nested manner.

example output:

```
let items = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "reply": [
            {
                "id": 50,
                "reply": [
                    id: 51,
                    reply: []
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "reply": [
            {
                "id": 52,
                "reply": []
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please come back with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By not showing anything about how your service is setup, the only advice I can give is to read the [monodb documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb), as queries like the one you are describing are pretty common.

Comment: if you have only 2 levels, comment + 1 array of replies (without more nesting), i think it will be simple. If you have free nesting like comment,reply,reply on reply, reply on reply on reply etc it will be complicated. Youtube style comments+replies i think are simple ones.